# Creating pair object c++

Tags: c++

Why it's not possible to create a pair object in the following way:

```
pair<int,int> p1 = {0,42}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible?

Comment: If you are compiling under Linux, try linking with -std=c++11. Provided you've included the semi colon etc, it should work fine.

Answer (score 8):

in C++03 you should use

```
std::make_pair(0, 42);
```

since pair is not simple data-structure.
or by calling constructor of pair i.e.

```
std::pair<int, int> p1(0, 42);
```

in C++11

`pair<int, int> p1 = {0, 42}`

is okay.

Answer (score 4):

Initializer list syntax is not allowed in C++03 because `std::pair` is not an *aggregate*, therefore the valid way of initializing is a constructor call.

Formal definition from the C++ standard (C++03 8.5.1 §1):

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

Please read [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/4178176#4178176) for a detailed explanation.

Things are changed in C++11 by introduction of `std::initializer_list`.